# Python Reddit PRAW get top week. How to change limit?

Tags: python, reddit, praw

I have been familiarising  myself with PRAW for reddit.  I am trying to get the top x posts for the week, however I am having trouble changing the limit for the "top" method.

The documentation doesn't seem to mention how to do it, unless I am missing something.  I can change the time peroid ok by just passing in the string "week", but the limit has be flummoxed.  The image shows that there is a param for limit and it is set to 100.

```
    r = self.getReddit()
    sub = r.subreddit('CryptoCurrency')
    results = sub.top("week")
    for r in results:
        print(r.title)
```

[DOCS: subreddit.top()](https://praw.readthedocs.io/en/stable/code_overview/models/subreddit.html#praw.models.Subreddit.top)

[IMAGE: Inspect listing generator params](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2EzEf.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the docs you've linked:

> Additional keyword arguments are passed in the initialization of
> [ListingGenerator](https://praw.readthedocs.io/en/stable/code_overview/other/listinggenerator.html#praw.models.ListingGenerator).

So we follow that link and see the `limit` parameter for `ListingGenerator`:

> limit – The number of content entries to fetch. If limit is None, then
> fetch as many entries as possible. Most of reddit’s listings contain a
> maximum of 1000 items, and are returned 100 at a time. This class will
> automatically issue all necessary requests (default: 100).

So using the following should do it for you:

```
 results = sub.top("week", limit=500)
```

Comment: Thank you, I clearly didn't understand the ListingGenerator.