# PRAW doesn't understand keyword argument after

Tags: python, typeerror, reddit, traceback, praw

I am trying to write a program in python, which gets me a post from reddit with more than 100 comments, from which one needs to have over 100 Words. That comment in combination with the title i would like to have.
This is my Code, except login Data:

```
subreddit_to_scrape = "askreddit"
used_posts_file = "C:\\Users\\Yoga Duet 7\\OneDrive - BRG Kepler\\alt\\Desktop\\RedditBot\\used_posts.txt"


import praw

reddit = praw.Reddit(
    client_id=REDDIT_CLIENT_ID,
    client_secret=REDDIT_SECRET_KEY,
    username=REDDIT_USERNAME,
    password=REDDIT_PASSWORD,
    user_agent=REDDIT_USER_AGENT)


def get_new_posts(subreddit_to_scrape, after=None, limit=1):
    subreddit = reddit.subreddit(subreddit_to_scrape)
    if after is not None:
        new_post = subreddit.new(limit=limit, after=after)
    else:
        new_post = subreddit.new(limit=limit)
    return new_post

def add_new_post(subreddit_to_scrape, list=None):
    new_post = True
    after = ""
    while new_post:
        if after != "":
            posts = get_new_posts(subreddit_to_scrape, after)
        else:
            posts = get_new_posts(subreddit_to_scrape)
        for post in posts:
            post.comments.replace_more()
            print(len(post.comments.list()))
            if len(post.comments.list()) >= 100:
                for comment in post.comments.list():
                    if len(comment.body) >= 100:
                        new_post = False
                        return post.title, comment.body
                    else:
                        after = post.id
            else:
                after = post.id



print(add_new_post(subreddit_to_scrape))
```

And this is the error:

```
python main.py
0
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Yoga Duet 7\OneDrive - BRG Kepler\alt\Desktop\RedditBot\main.py", line 52, in <module>
    print(add_new_post(subreddit_to_scrape))
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Yoga Duet 7\OneDrive - BRG Kepler\alt\Desktop\RedditBot\main.py", line 34, in add_new_post
    posts = get_new_posts(subreddit_to_scrape, after)
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Yoga Duet 7\OneDrive - BRG Kepler\alt\Desktop\RedditBot\main.py", line 24, in get_new_posts
    new_post = subreddit.new(limit=limit, after=after)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Python311\Lib\site-packages\praw\models\listing\mixins\base.py", line 115, in new
    return ListingGenerator(self._reddit, url, **generator_kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
TypeError: ListingGenerator.__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'after'
```

So I am not sure on what to do now.

I already tried replacing the after with before, same error, but i think  after is what i need.

Comment: This error traceback doesn't look like it's from the given code as there is no line ```posts = get_new_posts(subreddit_to_scrape, after)```.

Comment: In the second function after the first if

Comment: Well, guess this means I need to step away from the keyboard as I don't see it.

Comment: Im sorry, Im blind, i posted the code version with before, wait a second

Comment: Your error message and your code don't match.   I don't see ```new_posts = subreddit.new(**params)```.

Comment: I dont see where you saw that line

Answer (score 3):

Solved. I needet to pass the 'after' argument as a parameter like this:

```
new_post = subreddit.new(limit=limit, params={'after': after})
```

Comment: I don't see anything about `limit` or `params` in the praw documentation, how did you find out that you can use these arguments? I'd like something similar for search if possible. EDIT: after a search I found an answer that explains it. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68557668/python-reddit-praw-get-top-week-how-to-change-limit